# You are known for your "faux pas"

Tags: grammatical-number

In the title, and without being spoken out loud, the usage of faux pas is vague as to whether it's singular or plural.

Is it therefore grammatically incorrect, ie. the statement needs to be re-written another way to disambiguate itself?

Comment: This is one of many cases (*bass, read, tear, rendezvous*) where English spelling isn't adequate to determine the pronunciation of a word. Short of spelling reform (which isn't likely), there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: No, it's correct. Yes, you might want to find a less ambiguous wording.

Comment: The sentence wouldn't have occurred in isolation.  In a real context, if the sentence had referred to a specific faux pas, there would almost certainly have been a previous reference to it in the text or conversation.  Otherwise, it is a general statement about social awkwardness and, consequently, faux pas would be interpreted as plural.

Comment: A majority of the time will just come down to the context before the sentence containing faux pas. This contextual evidence is only necessary if someone other than the person who wrote it is reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 'You are known for your faux pas', 'faux pas' can be a singular noun or a plural noun. This makes the sentence ambiguous; nonetheless, it is grammatical. Grammatical sentences may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It's not grammatically incorrect, but you can rewrite it if you are worried about potential misunderstanding. Something like “*You are known for your many faux pas*” for plural or “*You are known for a faux pas that you have committed*” for singular could work.

Comment: Agreed, if the OP is really asking two questions: "Is it grammatically incorrect?" and "Should it be re-written?" In that case, the answers are "No" and "Yes, if you want to be more clear".

Comment: I suspect most people would use "You are known for *your* faux pas" for plural problems and "…*that* faux pas" for an oft-repeated singular…